# What is the medoid function and its relation to the median?

Tags: optimization, median, robust, norm

> The medoid function is defined in this  [graph neural network paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.15651.pdf) as:
> $$ t := \arg\min_{y\in \mathcal{X}}\sum_{j=1}^N||x_j-y||$$
> which is a "multivariate generalization of the Median" and $\mathcal{X}=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ is a collection of points in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

How does this relate to the median in higher dimensions? In $\mathbb{R}^1$, the median uses an ordered list of data-points and finds the central point, what does it mean to find the median in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and beyond, and how does this function do it?

I've never seen this function before, so i wonder if it has it's drawbacks and if there are better formulas to use? Furthermore, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medoid) states the medoid "is not equivalent to a median" so is this paper wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In one dimension, the median minimises the sum of absolute values of distances,
$$\textrm{median} = \arg\min_m \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i-m|$$
and thus is a medoid. In that sense it's a generalisation of the median, and it's a reasonable location summary. As Wikipedia goes on to say, medoids aren't equivalent to medians in general, because medians are really a one-dimensional concept.

There are  multiple generalisations of the median to higher dimensions, all trying to preserve some properties of the median, and they are all different. A geometric median is like a medoid except it doesn't have to be one of the sample points; [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1403809) reviews some other definitions of higher-dimensional medians

Comment: OK and in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the median would just be finding the minimum value of $m_j=(a,b)$ of the euclidean distance? i.e. $\arg \min_m \sum_{i=1}^N \sqrt{(x_{i1}-m_1)^2+ (x_{i2}-m_2)^2}$?

Comment: That would be another possible generalisation, and it's called  the "geometric median".  But the minimum over all $(m_1, m_2)$ is not (in general) one of the data points.